# How to replace column name contained in another column by that column's value using PySpark?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark Dataframe as below:

| ID | col1 | col2 | colA | colB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id_1 | %colA | t < %colA | int1 | int3 |
| Id_2 | %colB | t < %colB | int2 | int4 |

I want to replace strings starting with % with it's corresponding column value as below.

| ID | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id_1 | int1 | t < int1 |
| Id_2 | int4 | t < int4 |

May be if I can loop through the rows, it is possible.

But is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the option to transform the necessary columns into the `map<string, string>` data type, enabling you to subsequently use these columns for value lookups within the `map`, like below.

```
df.withColumn(
  "mp", 
   expr("from_json(to_json(struct(*)),'map<string,string>')")
)
.withColumn(
  "col1", 
   expr("split(col1, '%')")
)
.withColumn(
  "col2", 
   expr("split(col2, '%')")
)
.selectExpr(
    "id", 
    "concat(col1[0],mp[col1[1]]) as col1", 
    "concat(col2[0],mp[col2[1]]) as col2", 
).show(false)
```

```
+----+----+------+
|id  |col1|col2  |
+----+----+------+
|id_1|int1|t<int1|
|id_2|int4|t<int4|
+----+----+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution where we can leverage efficiency of Regex, Also as we are using spark functions, sparks internal optimizer will also help increasing efficiency compare to writing user defined iterating solutions.

```
dfSchema = StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("col1", StringType(), True),
    StructField("col2", StringType(), True),
    StructField("colA", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("colB", IntegerType(), True),
])
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ["id_1", "%colA", "t < %colA", 10, 20],
    ["id_2", "%colB", "t < %colB", 30, 40]
], schema=dfSchema)

df.show()

from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract, col, when, regexp_replace
df.withColumn("col3", regexp_extract(col("col1"), r"(?<=\%).*", 0)) \
    .withColumn("col1", when(col("col3") == "colA", col("colA")).when(col("col3") == "colB", col("colB"))) \
    .withColumn("col4", regexp_extract(col("col2"), r"(?<=\%)(.*)", 1))\
    .withColumn("col5", when(col("col4") == "colA", col("colA")).when(col("col4") == "colB", col("colB")))\
    .withColumn("col2", regexp_replace(col("col2"), r"%(.*)[^\s]", col("col5")))\
.show()
```

```
+----+-----+---------+----+----+
|  id| col1|     col2|colA|colB|
+----+-----+---------+----+----+
|id_1|%colA|t < %colA|  10|  20|
|id_2|%colB|t < %colB|  30|  40|
+----+-----+---------+----+----+

+----+----+------+----+----+----+----+----+
|  id|col1|  col2|colA|colB|col3|col4|col5|
+----+----+------+----+----+----+----+----+
|id_1|  10|t < 10|  10|  20|colA|colA|  10|
|id_2|  40|t < 40|  30|  40|colB|colB|  40|
+----+----+------+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Have kept temp columns for explanation. You can drop it.

Comment: I was expecting a more generic answer, where there can be more columns like colA and colB. Sorry I wasn't clear before.